# Is there a way to configure log4j to ignore subpackages with a regular expression (REGEX)?

Tags: regex, logging, log4j

I am using log4j in my application.

If I want to turn on logging for a package I can simple do the below [in my log4j.properties file]:
`log4j.logger.com.myorg.somepackage= DEBUG`
This will cause log4j to log any messages from "com.myorg.somepackage" to my root logger.

My problem is, how do I stop logging from a package if I use plugins like maven shade?

For example, let's say you have package "com.myorg.somepackage" which is relocated (via maven shade plugin) to "com.someotherorg.dependency.com.myorg.somepackage".

If I wanted to set the level to warn I know I could do the below:
`log4j.logger.com.someotherorg.dependency.com.myorg.somepackage= WARN`

However, in my case, the dependency is shaded for multiple projects and I dont want to have to:
`log4j.logger.com.someotherorg.dependency.com.myorg.somepackage= WARN`
`log4j.logger.com.someotherorg1.dependency.com.myorg.somepackage= WARN`
`log4j.logger.com.someotherorg2.dependency.com.myorg.somepackage= WARN`
...etc

So how can I have log4j ignore "com.myorg.somepackage" regardless of where it lies in the package name? Is there some sort of REGEX I don't know about for this?

I would like to do something along the lines of:
`log4j.logger.*.com.myorg.somepackage= WARN`
but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find default functionality to do this in log4j, however log4j does allow you to create your own filters.

Here is what I did to resolve it:

`import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.Filter;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;`

public class CustomFilterer extends Filter {

```
@Override
public int decide(LoggingEvent event) {
    if (!event.getLoggerName().contains("com.myorg.somepackage")) {
        return Filter.NEUTRAL;
    } else {
        if (event.getLevel().isGreaterOrEqual(Level.WARN)) {
            return Filter.NEUTRAL;

        } else {
            return Filter.DENY;
        }
    }
}
```

}
`